# Marshalling Spring Data REST Query Results with RestTemplate

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-rest, resttemplate

When using `RestTemplate.exchange` to invoke a query endpoint, what return type should I expect?

My repository has a method thus:

`Page<Account> findAccountByFirstName(String name, Pageable pageable);`

In my integration test, I'm making the following call with a `RestTemplate`:

```
ResponseEntity<List<Account>> accountResponse = restPleb.exchange(
    new RequestEntity<Void>(HttpMethod.GET, getUri("/accounts/search/findByFirstName?firstName=Kevin")), 
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Account>>() {}
);
```

The response has the list of found resources in an object called `accounts`:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "accounts" : [ {
      "lastName" : "Lastname",
      "firstName" : "Kevin",
      "phoneNumber " : "+44 7700000000",
      "email" : "kevin@example.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:53826/accounts/id"
        },
        "persistableAccount" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:53826/accounts/id"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:53826/accounts/search/findByFirstName?firstName=Kevin"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

I get the following error where between them `RestTemplate` and Jackson can't figure out what to do with the response. Presumably this is because it's expecting an array rather than an object.

`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token`

Is there any way of getting `RestTemplate` to give the right hints to Jackson to deserialize this properly? I would have thought that there must be a way, being that it's Spring on both sides of the divide!

**Update**

I've tried specifying the response type as `Resources<Account>`, which prevents an exception being thrown gives an empty list instead: `Resources { content: [], links: [] }`

Comment: Are u checking for accountResponse.getBody() ? Giving you list of Account ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri an exception is thrown before the `exchange` call is completed, so `accountResponse` never gets assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-06), it has to be parsed in a different manner is what I suppose. Can this example be used to parse - defined [here](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/11/spring-resttemplate-with-linked-resource.html)

Registering the converter to the template -> and using the resource to parse the response.

```
public RestTemplate getRestTemplateWithHalMessageConverter() {
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> existingConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
 List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> newConverters = new ArrayList<>();
 newConverters.add(getHalMessageConverter());
 newConverters.addAll(existingConverters);
 restTemplate.setMessageConverters(newConverters);
 return restTemplate;
}
 
private HttpMessageConverter getHalMessageConverter() {
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
 MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter = new TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ResourceSupport.class);
 halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(HAL_JSON));
 halConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
 return halConverter;
}
```